# Passing parameters to .exe file within cmd

Tags: python, cmd, automation, parameter-passing

So I have an .exe tool that needs to be executed in cmd that's used to convert some GIS data from one format to BAG format.  The syntax looks like so:

```
C:\Caris\BDB\4.0\bin > carisbatch -r SurfacetoBAG [options] "input_file" "output_file"
```

I have a directory of about 40 files of GIS data, so I'd like to know how to automate the above cmd tool such that it will run through use all 40 files as "input_file".  I've looked into using the subprocess() module wrapped in a for loop with python, but I am under the impression it can only be used for unix systems.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can use subprocess no problem on windows ...
example to follow

```
import subprocess

for file in my_files:
    subprocess.Popen(["C:/Caris/BDB/4.0/bin/carisbatch.exe",'-r','SurfacetoBAGfile',file+".output"])
```

if you need to do it without the list format

```
for file in my_files:
    subprocess.Popen('C:/Caris/BDB/4.0/bin/carisbatch.exe -r SurfacetoBAGfile "{0}" "{0}.output"'.format(file),shell=True)
```

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for! The issue is that carisbatch.exe contains multiple other modules, so SurfacetoBAG needs to be specified as the module to be used.  My solution is to set "shell=true" within the subprocess call, so I can keep the original cmd syntax shown in my post.  My next question is how I'd pass in "file" as a parameter in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you import os, you should be able to use
    os.system('your command')

Regardless of platform (of course, the command string will vary between platforms)

Comment: you can also use subprocess regardless of platform ... +1 however since imho os.system/os.popen are easier to use than subproccess for beginners ... (although everywhere you read it seems like this is discouraged)